# Using a buffer reader to read blocks of data for a given input

Tags: java, bufferedreader

So this is the structure of the file that I'm reading from:

```
[MESSAGE BEGIN]
uan:123
messageID: 111
[MESSAGE END]
[MESSAGE BEGIN]
uan:123
status:test
[MESSAGE END]
```

What I'm trying to do is, for a given uan, return all the details for it, whilst maintaining the block structure "MESSAGE BEGIN" "MESSAGE END".

This is the code I've written:

```
startPattern= "uan:123"
endPattern= "[MESSAGE END]"
 System.out.println("Matching: " + this.getStartPattern());
        List<String> desiredLines = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader buff = Files.newBufferedReader(getPath())) {
            String line = "";
            while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.contains(this.getStartPattern())) {
                    desiredLines.add(line);
                    System.out.println(" \nMatch Found! ");
                    buff.lines().forEach(streamElement -> {
                        if (!streamElement.contains(this.getEndPattern())) {
                            desiredLines.add(streamElement);
                        } else if (streamElement.contains(this.getEndPattern())) {
                            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Exit Status 0");
                        }
                    });

                }
```

Now, the problem is, the while condition breaks when it sees the first "uan" and just captures the message ID. I want the code to also include "status" when I pass the uan.

Can anyone help with this?

**EDIT**

This is my expected output:

```
 uan:123
 messageID: 111
 uan:123
 status:test
```

All instances of uan:123 should be captured

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What I want is the following: uan:123
messageID: 111 uan:123
status:test Essentially, all instances of where uan:123 exist, should be returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Grouping filtered messages

Your general approach seems good. Instead of the nested loop I would break it down to a simpler and more straightforward logic like:

```
String needle = "uan:123";

String startPattern = "[MESSAGE BEGIN]";
String endPattern = "[MESSAGE END]";

List<List<String>>> result = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader buff = Files.newBufferedReader(getPath())) {
    // Lines and flag for current message
    List<String> currentMessage = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean messageContainedNeedle = false;

    // Read all lines
    while (true) {
        String line = buff.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }

        // Collect current line to message, ignore indicator
        if (!line.equals(endPattern) && !line.equals(startPattern)) {
            currentMessage.add(line);
        }

        // Set flag if message contains needle
        if (!messageContainedNeedle && line.equals(needle)) {
            messageContainedNeedle = true;
        }

        // Message ends
        if (line.equals(endPattern)) {
            // Collect if needle was contained
            if (messageContainedNeedle) {
                result.add(currentMessage);
            }

            // Prepare for next message
            messageContainedNeedle = false;
            currentMessage = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

It's easier to read and understand. And it supports that your message items come in arbitrary order. Also, the resulting `result` does still group messages in a `List<List<String>>`. You can easily flat-map that if you still want a `List<String>`.

The resulting structure is:

```
[
    ["uan:123", "messageID: 111"],
    ["uan:123", "status: test"]
]
```

Achieving exactly your desired output is simple now:

```
// Variant 1: Nested for-each
result.forEach(message -> message.forEach(System.out::println));

// Variant 2: Flat-map
result.stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(System.out::println));

// Variant 3: Without streams
for (List<String> message : result) {
    for (String line : message) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

---

### Grouping all messages

If you leave out the flag-part you can parse all messages into that structure and then easily stream on them:

```
public static List<List<String>> parseMessages(Path path) {
    String startPattern = "[MESSAGE BEGIN]";
    String endPattern = "[MESSAGE END]";

    List<List<String>>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader buff = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
        // Data for current message
        List<String> currentMessage = new ArrayList<>();

        // Read all lines
        while (true) {
            String line = buff.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }

            // Collect current line to message, ignore indicator
            if (!line.equals(endPattern) && !line.equals(startPattern)) {
                currentMessage.add(line);
            }

            // Message ends
            if (line.equals(endPattern)) {
                // Collect message
                result.add(currentMessage);

                // Prepare for next message
                currentMessage = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage is simple and straightforward. For example, filtering for messages with `"uan:123"`:

```
List<List<String>> messages = parseMessages(getPath());

String needle = "uan:123";
List<List<String>> messagesWithNeedle = messages.stream()
    .filter(message -> message.contains(needle))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The resulting structure again is:

```
[
    ["uan:123", "messageID: 111"],
    ["uan:123", "status: test"]
]
```

Achieving your desired output can be made directly on the stream cascade:

```
messages.stream()  // Stream<List<String>>
    .filter(message -> message.contains(needle))
    .flatMap(List::stream)  // Stream<String>
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

### Message Container

A natural idea would be to group the message data in a designated `Message` container class. Something like that:

```
public class Message {
    private final Map<String, String> mProperties;

    public Message() {
        mProperties = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public String getValue(String key) {
        return mProperties.get(key);
    }

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        mProperties.put(key, value);
    }

    public static Message fromLines(List<String> lines) {
        Message message = new Message();
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] data = line.split(":");
            message.put(data[0].trim(), data[1].trim());
        }
        return message;
    }

    // Other methods ...
}
```

Note the handy `Message#fromLines` method. Using that you get a `List<Message>` and working with the data is way more convenient.

Comment: This looks good, will try to implement the "group messaging" solution. Just a quick question, do I return the currentMessage in the parseMessages method? It requires a return statement

Comment: @Matt Yes, `result` is to be returned. Corrected, sorry.

Comment: quick question, with regards to this line of code:   .collect(Collectors.toList()), how do I print out the final output?

Comment: @Matt Please read and understand the answer. I have given you the code to achieve that already: `result.forEach(message -> message.forEach(System.out::println));` or `result.stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(System.out::println));`. See the end of the first passage. And the end of the second has the print in it too, directly in the stream cascade if you don't want to collect. Also, if an answer helped please consider up-voting and/or accepting it, thanks.

Comment: No I get that, I meant, once you've called the parsemessages method , you're capturing the result list in a new list called "messages". And from there, you're filtering that message for a particular value. At that point I need to print out the output, but the code youve provided i.e. messages.stream()  // Stream<List<String>>
    .filter(message -> message.contains(needle))
    .flatMap(List::stream)  // Stream<String>
    .forEach(System.out::println); doesn't seem to be printing into my console

Comment: In both examples the loop collects the whole message (consisting of multiple lines) into a list `messages`. The first example sets and remembers a flag if it found the needle. But the message is completed at the point where it is saved inside `result`. The first example only collects messages that matched the needle. The second example collects all first. In both examples you can easily stream and print results. Filtering is done in the first already, since only matching messages where collected. In the second example you still need to filter. I have shown all variants in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about to create e.g. `Data` class, that holds all fields for given `uan`? I can see that you have an object with id (i.e. uan) and many messaged for this object.

I offer to use this approach and collect all relative information (belong to the same object with `uan`) in the same instance:

This is `Data` class:

```
final class Data {

    private String uan;
    private final List<Map<String, String>> events = new LinkedList<>();

    public Data(String uan) {
        this.uan = uan;
    }

    public String getUan() {
        return uan;
    }

    public boolean hasUan() {
        return uan != null && !uan.isEmpty();
    }

    public void set(Data data) {
        if (data != null)
            events.addAll(data.events);
    }

    public void addEvent(String key, String value) {
        if ("uan".equalsIgnoreCase(key))
            uan = value;
        else
            events.add(Collections.singletonMap(key, value));
    }
}
```

This is method that reads given file and retrieves `Map<String, Data>` with key as `uan` and values are all data for this object:

```
private static final String BEGIN = "[MESSAGE BEGIN]";
private static final String END = "[MESSAGE END]";
private static final Pattern KEY_VALUE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?<key>[^:]+)\\s*:\\s*(?<value>[^:]+)\\s*");

private static Map<String, Data> readFile(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        Data data = null;
        Map<String, Data> map = new TreeMap<>();

        for (String str; (str = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(BEGIN))
                data = new Data(null);
            else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(END)) {
                if (data != null && data.hasUan()) {
                    String uan = data.getUan();
                    map.putIfAbsent(uan, new Data(uan));
                    map.get(uan).set(data);
                }

                data = null;
            } else if (data != null) {
                Matcher matcher = KEY_VALUE_PATTERN.matcher(str);

                if (matcher.matches())
                    data.addEvent(matcher.group("key"), matcher.group("value"));
            }
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is like the client looks like:

```
Map<String, Data> map = readFile(new FileReader("data.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple parsing logic and only output data if you see the matching `uan`.  I use a boolean variable to keep track of whether we have hit a matching `uan` inside a given block.  If so, then we output all lines, otherwise we no-op and skip everything.

```
try (BufferedReader buff = Files.newBufferedReader(getPath())) {
    String line = "";
    String uan = "uan:123";
    String begin = "[MESSAGE BEGIN]";
    String end = "[MESSAGE END]";
    boolean match = false;

    while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
        if (uan.equals(line)) {
            match = true;
        }
        else if (end.equals(line)) {
            match = false;
        }
        else if (!begin.equals(line) && match) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I don't do any validation to check if, for example, every `BEGIN` is mirrored by a proper closing `END`.  If you need this you may add extra logic to the above code.

Comment: but that would only print out: uan:123
 messageID: 111

Comment: @Matt No, it would print out all content.  I haven't tested the code, but it should work.